# google play console does not supported less then 26 Targetsdkversion?

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap

My application is not working in android 7.0,6.0,5.0 version because of

> 

```
   <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="26"/>
```

when i host lower then this SdkVersion like 22,24 then google play console gives me error that "minimum target version 26 required" and my application only working in andriod 8.0 (Orio)

**how to work android 6.0,5.0 and more...** using phone gap app.

Answer (score 0):

Google now requires every app that is published to google play to have the target SDK version of 26

https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk

Answer (score 0):

your target sdk version must be 26, but your minimum sdk version can be anything.

so for example you can set the minimum sdk version to be 15 but the maximum must be 26